# Finding the pdf of $\sqrt X$ when $X\sim U(0,3)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed random variable over $(0, 3)$, find the probability density function of $Y = \sqrt{X}$ , $f_y(y)$, in explicit formula.

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040283/find-the-probability-density-function-of-y-x2) What I got so far:

$F_y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(\sqrt x \le y) = P(x \le y^2)  = F_x(y^2) = \int^{y^2}_0 \frac{1}{3} dt = \frac{1}{3}t |^{y^2}_0 = \frac{1}{3}y^2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Where did you stuck?

Comment: Found. Now what should I do with it?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness! Just updated the question @Did

Comment: Modulo some annoying typos and an annoying lack of conditions on $y$, yes.

Comment: Your $F_y=\frac13y^2$ with $0 \lt y \lt \sqrt{3}$ is the cumulative distribution function.  You need to take the derivative to get the density function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you can simply use the transformation formula to find directly the density of $Y$. $g(X) = \sqrt{X}$ is monotone (increasing) function on $[0,3]$, and $g^{-1}(Y) = Y^2$, thus
$$
f_Y(y) = f_Y(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| = \frac{2}{3}y, \quad y\in (0,\sqrt{3}).
$$

Recall that the density function is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function, i.e., 
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}P(Y\le y),  
$$
in your case you can verify that
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}\frac{y^2}{3} =\frac{2}{3}y.
$$

Comment: So your answer is $\frac{2}{3} y$ does that mean my answer $\frac{1}{3} y^2$ is incorrect?

Comment: No, you have the cumulative distribution function, i.e., $F'_Y(y) = (y^2/3)' = 2y/3=f_Y(y)$.

Comment: Oh I get it. So should the $f_y(y)  = 2y/3$ and $F_y(y) = 1/3 y^2$?

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: @Alexander That should be $f_Y(y)$ and $F_Y(y)$.  Case sensitivity is important.