# What is the distribution of $\left (\mathbf x^{\dagger}\mathbf x\right )^2$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

Let $\mathbf x=[x_1, ... ,x_K]^T$, $x\sim\mathcal C\mathcal N(\mathbf 0,\sigma_x^2\mathbf I)$, I believe that the distribution of $||\mathbf x||^2=\mathbf x^{\dagger}\mathbf x$ is Erlang (Please see attached photo from "Performance analysis of cloud radio access networks with distributed multiple antenna remote radio heads"). Is there anything known about the distribution of $\left (\mathbf x^{\dagger}\mathbf x\right )^2$? If not, does it converge in distribution? How can we know which distribution? If yes, can we prove it?

[image]

Comment: What is the $CN$ distribution? If you mean the normal density than the modulus square would be just $\sim \sigma_x^2 \chi_n$, where $\chi$ is the chi squared distribution so I guess you mean a different distribution ?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. CN is for complex Gaussian. Is it Erlang or Chi square?

Comment: I see. So the complex normal squared has a $\chi_2$ distribution, i.e. the chi squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. This turns out to be the exponential distribution (check the p.d.f. on Wikipedia of the chisquared with 2 degrees of freedom). That is why than summing over n we get the Erlang distribution, defined as the sum of exponential variables. But note that this reasoning shows than the Erlang with n degrees of freedom is a very close parent of the chi-squared distribution with 2n degrees of freedoms (again we can compare the PDF to be sure...)

Comment: Thank @Thomas How about $\left (\mathbf x^{\dagger}\mathbf x\right )^2$?

Comment: It'll be a [generalized gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) with $p=1/2$ - try calculating the pdf.

Comment: Dap is right. It is just a change of variables as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040283/find-the-probability-density-function-of-y-x2/1040339 . The result in my answer is only asymptotic :)

Comment: @Thomas why did you assume Gaussian pdf? why not other pdf? Or does it mean when we work asymptotically, do we always consider Gaussian?

Comment: @AymenKareem If your question is about my asymptotic answer could you make your comment down my answer si that I can answer there ?

Comment: (not related to the question) By the way, to derive eq. 40 one would need the assumption that d_n and g_n are independent I guess ?

Comment: @Thomas actually I didn't get it how they get to eq. 40. Can u tell me how?

Comment: Symbolically $F_U(y)=P(U\le y)=\int dx P(1/(1+d) |g|^2 \le y| d=x)*P(d=x)=\int dx P(|g|^2 \le (1+d)y| d=x)*P(d=x)$. Now if $d$ and $|g|^2$ and independent $P(|g|^2 \le (1+d)y| d=x)=P(|g|^2 \le (1+x)y)$ and everything follows. Otherwise I would not know... There seems also to be a cutoff on the possible values of $d$...

Comment: @Dap could u provide some detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I can say for the moment. We have from the discussion:

$V \equiv x^+x \sim \sum_{i=1}^N e_i$

where $e_i$ are independent and exponentially distributed $e_i \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

Than we have $V^2=(x^+x)^2 \sim \sum_{i,j}e_ie_j$. This is the variable we are interested in. Let's try some asymptotics.

If we call $S_N= V/N$ by the central limit theorem for $N$ large:

$(S_N-\frac{1}{\lambda})\sqrt{N} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{\lambda^2})$ [1]

applying the delta method with $g(x)=x^2$:

$(S^2_N-\frac{1}{\lambda^2})\sqrt{N} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{4}{\lambda^4})$

and $V^2=S_N^2N^2$ so that:

$(\frac{V^2}{N^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2})\sqrt{N} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{4}{\lambda^4})$ [2]

and informally :

$V^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\frac{N^2}{\lambda^2},\frac{4}{\lambda^4}N^3)$

All convergences are intended in distribution.

Comment: Thank you. I guess $K=N$ here. My simulation shows that Gaussian distribution with mean $K(K+1)$ and variance $K(K+1)(K+2)(K+3)-mean^2$ fits better. Actually, Gamma distribution is even better.

Comment: Yes you are right. Good that we have the same thermodynamic scaling. For finite N results you can apply the change of variables formula as Dap suggests in the comments.

Comment: sorry for using the word "thermodynamic", my physics background is hard to hide :D

Comment: Why did you assume Gaussian pdf? why not other pdf? Or does it mean when we work asymptotically, do we always consider Gaussian?

Comment: I did not assume Gaussian pdfs. The $e_i$ are exponentially distributed. Than equation [1] follows from the central limit theorem and is indeed independent from the distribution of the $e_i$ (law of large numbers). Equation [2] follows from [1] by the delta method.